# ¿Cómo evitar pasar al siguiente si no están completados los campos?

Tags: jquery

Querría saber cómo deshabilitar el botón `Next Section` -> `<a class="btn" id="next">Next Section ▷</a>` utilizando `jQuery` cuando los campos del formulario están vacíos sin importar el tipo de campo que sea `input, textarea, select, radio, checkbox` entre otros, ya la validación de datos del formulario lo estoy validando con `ajax` y `PHP` correctamente.

Con Ajax envío y recibo la información de la siguiente manera [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h8nkyfzc/) y, con PHP valido la información:

```
if (isset($_POST['publish'])) {

    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $language = $_POST["language"];

    if (empty($_POST['username'])){
        echo json_encode(['status'=> false, 'message'=> ["username" =>"Por favor, ingrese su usuario."]]);
        exit;
    }
    if (empty($_POST['language'])){
        echo json_encode(['status'=> false, 'message'=> ["language" =>"Por favor, seleccioné su idioma."]]);
        exit;
    }
}
```

La idea de todo es darle valor al `wizard` que una vez que todos los campos estén llenados entonces pasar al siguiente paso y, así sucesivamente, todo combinado con el pequeño `script wizard`, más `ajax` y `PHP`.

Este es el código completo:

```js
$("body").on("keyup", "form", function(e){
  if (e.which == 13){
    if ($("#next").is(":visible") && $("fieldset.current").find("input, textarea").valid() ){
      e.preventDefault();
      nextSection();
      return false;
    }
  }
});
 
$("#next").on("click", function(e){
  console.log(e.target);
  nextSection();
});
 
$("form").on("submit", function(e){
  if ($("#next").is(":visible") || $("fieldset.current").index() < 3){
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
 
function goToSection(i){
  $("fieldset:gt("+i+")").removeClass("current").addClass("next");
  $("fieldset:lt("+i+")").removeClass("current");
  $("li").eq(i).addClass("current").siblings().removeClass("current");
  setTimeout(function(){
    $("fieldset").eq(i).removeClass("next").addClass("current active");
      if ($("fieldset.current").index() == 3){
        $("#next").hide();
        $("input[type=submit]").show();
      } else {
        $("#next").show();
        $("input[type=submit]").hide();
      }
  }, 80);
}
function nextSection(){
  var i = $("fieldset.current").index();
  if (i < 3){
    $("li").eq(i+1).addClass("active");
    goToSection(i+1);
  }
}
$("li").on("click", function(e){
  var i = $(this).index();
  if ($(this).hasClass("active")){
    goToSection(i);
  } else {
    alert("Please complete previous sections first.");
  }
});
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Merriweather Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Merriweather Sans Light'), local('MerriweatherSans-Light'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/merriweathersans/v11/2-c49IRs1JiJN1FRAMjTN5zd9vgsFH1eYCDE0hM.ttf) format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Merriweather Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Merriweather Sans Bold'), local('MerriweatherSans-Bold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/merriweathersans/v11/2-c49IRs1JiJN1FRAMjTN5zd9vgsFH1OZyDE0hM.ttf) format('truetype');
}
body {
  background: url(http://farm5.staticflickr.com/4139/4825532997\_7a7cd3d640\_b.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Merriweather Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #666;
}
#form {
  width: 600px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 80px auto;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 300px;
}
#fieldsets {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}
input[type=text],
input[type=email],
input[type=password],
input[type=tel],
textarea {
  display: block;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  position: relative;
}
input[type=text]:focus,
input[type=email]:focus,
input[type=password]:focus,
input[type=tel]:focus,
textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #22918b;
}
input[type=radio] {
  margin: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
}
fieldset {
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: -640px;
  width: 600px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  opacity: 0;
}
fieldset.current {
  left: 20px;
  opacity: 1;
}
fieldset.next {
  left: 640px;
}
input[type=submit] {
  display: none;
  border: none;
}
#section-tabs {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  list-style: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#section-tabs li {
  color: #a7a7a7;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  border-left: 1px solid #aaa;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 6px;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 30px;
  background: #ddd;
  position: relative;
}
#section-tabs li span {
  color: #bababa;
}
#section-tabs li.active {
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#section-tabs li:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  margin-left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
#section-tabs li.current {
  opacity: 1;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 999;
  border-left: none;
}
#section-tabs li.current:after {
  border: 15px solid transparent;
  border-left: 15px solid #2cbab2;
}
.error {
  color: #bf2424;
  display: block;
}
input.error,
textarea.error {
  border-color: #bf2424;
}
input.error:focus,
textarea.error:focus {
  border-color: #bf2424;
}
label.error {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
input.valid {
  color: green;
}
label.valid {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
}
input + .valid,
textarea + .valid {
  display: none;
}
.valid + .valid {
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  margin-top: -36px;
  color: green;
}
.btn {
  border: none;
  padding: 8px;
  background: #2cbab2;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  font-family: 'Merriweather Sans', sans-serif;
}
.btn:hover {
  background: #26a19a;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" action="https://formsubmit.co/misrilanka.tk@gmail.com" method="POST">
    <ul id="section-tabs">
      <li class="current active"><span>1.</span> Creds</li>
      <li><span>2.</span> Deets</li>
      <li><span>3.</span> Settings</li>
      <li><span>4.</span> Last Words</li>
    </ul>
  <div id="fieldsets">
  <fieldset class="current">
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input name="email" type="email" class="required email" />
    <label name="password" for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" minlength="10" class="required">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="next">
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input name="username" type="text">
    <label for="bio">Short Bio:</label>
    <textarea name="bio" class="required"></textarea>
    <select name="language">
        <option value="">Idioma</option>
        <option value="es">Español</option>
        <option value="en">Inglés</option>
    </select>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="next">
    <label for="interests">Basic Interests:</label>
    <textarea name="bio"></textarea>
    <p>Receive newsletter?<br>
      <input type="radio" name="newsletter" value="yes"><label for="newsletter">yes</label>
      <input type="radio" name="newsletter" value="no"><label for="newsletter">no</label>
    </p>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="next">
    <label for="referrer">Referred by:</label>
    <input type="text" name="referrer">
    <label for="phone">Daytime Phone:</label>
    <input type="tel" name="phone">
  </fieldset>
  <a class="btn" id="next">Next Section ▷</a>
  <input type="submit" name="publish" class="btn" id="publish">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Porque no agragas `required`

Comment: @alanfcm no me agradan, dañan el aspecto al diseño /:

Comment: Tambien puedes usar una libreria de validacion como: https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: @alanfcm Ya valide los datos con PHP y ajax, ahora solo me falta combinar el script del wizard con las validaciones

Comment: Esto se podría reconstruir de manera mucho más simple sin usar jQuery y sin ningún framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Este código no deshabilita el botón "Next Section", pero no permite que pases de sección sin haber completado los campos, mostrándote una alerta. Toda la lógica está en la función "seccionCompletada" espero te ayude.

```js
$("body").on("keyup", "form", function(e){
  if (e.which == 13){
    if ($("#next").is(":visible") && $("fieldset.current").find("input, textarea").valid() ){
      e.preventDefault();
      nextSection();
      return false;
    }
  }
});
 
$("#next").on("click", function(e){
  console.log(e.target);
  nextSection();
});
 
$("form").on("submit", function(e){
  if ($("#next").is(":visible") || $("fieldset.current").index() < 3){
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
 
function goToSection(i){
  $("fieldset:gt("+i+")").removeClass("current").addClass("next");
  $("fieldset:lt("+i+")").removeClass("current");
  $("li").eq(i).addClass("current").siblings().removeClass("current");
  setTimeout(function(){
    $("fieldset").eq(i).removeClass("next").addClass("current active");
      if ($("fieldset.current").index() == 3){
        $("#next").hide();
        $("input[type=submit]").show();
      } else {
        $("#next").show();
        $("input[type=submit]").hide();
      }
  }, 80);
}

function seccionCompletada(seccion) {
 let fields = seccion.find('input, textarea, select');
 let fieldsVacios = fields.filter(function(item) {
  let input = $(fields[item]);
  if(input.prop('type') == 'checkbox' || input.prop('type') == 'radio') {
   return $(`input[name=${input.prop('name')}]`).is(':checked') ? false : true;
  }else {
   return input.val().trim() == ''; 
  }
 });
 
 return fieldsVacios.length ? false : true;
}


function nextSection(){
 let fieldSetCurrent = $("fieldset.current");
 
 if(seccionCompletada(fieldSetCurrent) == false) {
  alert('Completa los campos de esta sección');
  return;
 }
 
  var i = fieldSetCurrent.index();
  if (i < 3){
    $("li").eq(i+1).addClass("active");
    goToSection(i+1);
  }
}
$("li").on("click", function(e){
  var i = $(this).index();
  if ($(this).hasClass("active")){
    goToSection(i);
  } else {
    alert("Please complete previous sections first.");
  }
});
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Merriweather Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Merriweather Sans Light'), local('MerriweatherSans-Light'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/merriweathersans/v11/2-c49IRs1JiJN1FRAMjTN5zd9vgsFH1eYCDE0hM.ttf) format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Merriweather Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Merriweather Sans Bold'), local('MerriweatherSans-Bold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/merriweathersans/v11/2-c49IRs1JiJN1FRAMjTN5zd9vgsFH1OZyDE0hM.ttf) format('truetype');
}
body {
  background: url(http://farm5.staticflickr.com/4139/4825532997\_7a7cd3d640\_b.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Merriweather Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #666;
}
#form {
  width: 600px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 80px auto;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 300px;
}
#fieldsets {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}
input[type=text],
input[type=email],
input[type=password],
input[type=tel],
textarea {
  display: block;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  position: relative;
}
input[type=text]:focus,
input[type=email]:focus,
input[type=password]:focus,
input[type=tel]:focus,
textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #22918b;
}
input[type=radio] {
  margin: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
}
fieldset {
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: -640px;
  width: 600px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  opacity: 0;
}
fieldset.current {
  left: 20px;
  opacity: 1;
}
fieldset.next {
  left: 640px;
}
input[type=submit] {
  display: none;
  border: none;
}
#section-tabs {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  list-style: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#section-tabs li {
  color: #a7a7a7;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  border-left: 1px solid #aaa;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 6px;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 30px;
  background: #ddd;
  position: relative;
}
#section-tabs li span {
  color: #bababa;
}
#section-tabs li.active {
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#section-tabs li:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  margin-left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
#section-tabs li.current {
  opacity: 1;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 999;
  border-left: none;
}
#section-tabs li.current:after {
  border: 15px solid transparent;
  border-left: 15px solid #2cbab2;
}
.error {
  color: #bf2424;
  display: block;
}
input.error,
textarea.error {
  border-color: #bf2424;
}
input.error:focus,
textarea.error:focus {
  border-color: #bf2424;
}
label.error {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
input.valid {
  color: green;
}
label.valid {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
}
input + .valid,
textarea + .valid {
  display: none;
}
.valid + .valid {
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  margin-top: -36px;
  color: green;
}
.btn {
  border: none;
  padding: 8px;
  background: #2cbab2;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  font-family: 'Merriweather Sans', sans-serif;
}
.btn:hover {
  background: #26a19a;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" action="https://formsubmit.co/misrilanka.tk@gmail.com" method="POST">
    <ul id="section-tabs">
      <li class="current active"><span>1.</span> Creds</li>
      <li><span>2.</span> Deets</li>
      <li><span>3.</span> Settings</li>
      <li><span>4.</span> Last Words</li>
    </ul>
  <div id="fieldsets">
  <fieldset class="current">
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input name="email" type="email" class="required email" />
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input name="password" type="password" minlength="10" class="required">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="next">
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input name="username" type="text">
    <label for="bio">Short Bio:</label>
    <textarea name="bio" class="required"></textarea>
    <select name="language">
        <option value="">Idioma</option>
        <option value="es">Español</option>
        <option value="en">Inglés</option>
    </select>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="next">
    <label for="interests">Basic Interests:</label>
    <textarea name="bio"></textarea>
    <p>Receive newsletter?<br>
      <input type="radio" name="newsletter" value="yes"><label for="newsletter">yes</label>
      <input type="radio" name="newsletter" value="no"><label for="newsletter">no</label>
    </p>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="next">
    <label for="referrer">Referred by:</label>
    <input type="text" name="referrer">
    <label for="phone">Daytime Phone:</label>
    <input type="tel" name="phone">
  </fieldset>
  <a class="btn" id="next">Next Section ▷</a>
  <input type="submit" name="publish" class="btn" id="publish">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hola, se podría evitar el uso de advertencia en vez de ello que se muestre un mismo mensaje personalizado debajo de cada campo del formulario?

Answer (score 1):

En este ejemplo he usado la validación del navegador para la comprobación de los datos enviados a través del formulario.

El funcionamiento es el siguiente:

- He convertido el botón de avance de pestaña en el botón de envío del formulario. Éste no se envía si no se han rellenado todas las pestañas y los campos son correctos.
- Al activar cada pestaña:

  - Quito todos los atributos `required` de los campos de los formularios para evitar que los de otra pestaña bloqueen el avance.
  - Agrego el atributo `required` solo a aquellos elementos que tengan la clase `required`.

Espero que te sea de utilidad.

```js
$("body").on("keyup", "form", e => {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    if ($("#next").is(":visible")
      && $("fieldset.current").find("input, textarea").valid()
    ) {
      e.preventDefault();
      nextSection();
      return false;
    }
  }
});

/* Gestionamos la navegación a través del envío de formulario */
$("form").on("submit", function(e) {
  /* Si aún no hemos completado el formulario estamos pasando de pestaña */
  if ($("#next").is(":visible")
    || $("fieldset.current").index() < 3
  ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    nextSection();
  }
});

function goToSection(i) {
  /* Quitamos el atributo de "requerido" a los campos marcados */
  $("fieldset .required").removeAttr('required');
  $("fieldset:gt("+i+")").removeClass("current").addClass("next");
  $("fieldset:lt("+i+")").removeClass("current");
  $("li").eq(i).addClass("current").siblings().removeClass("current");
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("fieldset").eq(i).removeClass("next").addClass("current active");
    if ($("fieldset.current").index() == 3){
      $("#next").hide();
      $("input[type=submit]").show();
    } else {
      $("#next").show();
      $("input[type=submit]").hide();
    }
    /* Ponemos el atributo "requerido" a los campos marcados activados */
    $("fieldset.current .required").attr('required', true);
  }, 80);
}

function nextSection(){
  var i = $("fieldset.current").index();
  if (i < 3){
    $("li").eq(i+1).addClass("active");
    goToSection(i+1);
  }
}

$("li").on("click", e => {
  var i = $(this).index();
  if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
    goToSection(i);
  } else {
    alert("Please complete previous sections first.");
  }
});

/* Iniciamos el formulario, importante para activar los atributos iniciales */
goToSection(0);
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Merriweather Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Merriweather Sans Light'), local('MerriweatherSans-Light'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/merriweathersans/v11/2-c49IRs1JiJN1FRAMjTN5zd9vgsFH1eYCDE0hM.ttf) format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Merriweather Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Merriweather Sans Bold'), local('MerriweatherSans-Bold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/merriweathersans/v11/2-c49IRs1JiJN1FRAMjTN5zd9vgsFH1OZyDE0hM.ttf) format('truetype');
}
body {
  background: url(//farm5.staticflickr.com/4139/4825532997\_7a7cd3d640\_b.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Merriweather Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #666;
}
#form {
  width: 600px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 80px auto;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 300px;
}
#fieldsets {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}
input[type=text],
input[type=email],
input[type=password],
input[type=tel],
textarea {
  display: block;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  position: relative;
}
input[type=text]:focus,
input[type=email]:focus,
input[type=password]:focus,
input[type=tel]:focus,
textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #22918b;
}
input[type=radio] {
  margin: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
}
fieldset {
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: -640px;
  width: 600px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  opacity: 0;
}
fieldset.current {
  left: 20px;
  opacity: 1;
}
fieldset.next {
  left: 640px;
}
input[type=submit] {
  display: none;
  border: none;
}
#section-tabs {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  list-style: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#section-tabs li {
  color: #a7a7a7;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  border-left: 1px solid #aaa;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 6px;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 30px;
  background: #ddd;
  position: relative;
}
#section-tabs li span {
  color: #bababa;
}
#section-tabs li.active {
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#section-tabs li:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  margin-left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
#section-tabs li.current {
  opacity: 1;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 999;
  border-left: none;
}
#section-tabs li.current:after {
  border: 15px solid transparent;
  border-left: 15px solid #2cbab2;
}
.error {
  color: #bf2424;
  display: block;
}
input.error,
textarea.error {
  border-color: #bf2424;
}
input.error:focus,
textarea.error:focus {
  border-color: #bf2424;
}
label.error {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
input.valid {
  color: green;
}
label.valid {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
}
input + .valid,
textarea + .valid {
  display: none;
}
.valid + .valid {
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  margin-top: -36px;
  color: green;
}
.btn {
  border: none;
  padding: 8px;
  background: #2cbab2;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  font-family: 'Merriweather Sans', sans-serif;
}
.btn:hover {
  background: #26a19a;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" action="https://formsubmit.co/misrilanka.tk@gmail.com" method="POST">
    <ul id="section-tabs">
      <li class="current active"><span>1.</span> Creds</li>
      <li><span>2.</span> Deets</li>
      <li><span>3.</span> Settings</li>
      <li><span>4.</span> Last Words</li>
    </ul>
  <div id="fieldsets">
  <fieldset class="current">
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input name="email" type="email" class="required email" />
    <label name="password" for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" minlength="10" class="required" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="next">
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input name="username" type="text" />
    <label for="bio">Short Bio:</label>
    <textarea name="bio" class="required"></textarea>
    <select name="language">
        <option value="">Idioma</option>
        <option value="es">Español</option>
        <option value="en">Inglés</option>
    </select>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="next">
    <label for="interests">Basic Interests:</label>
    <textarea name="bio"></textarea>
    <p>Receive newsletter?<br>
      <input type="radio" name="newsletter" value="yes"><label for="newsletter">yes</label>
      <input type="radio" name="newsletter" value="no"><label for="newsletter">no</label>
    </p>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="next">
    <label for="referrer">Referred by:</label>
    <input type="text" name="referrer">
    <label for="phone">Daytime Phone:</label>
    <input type="tel" name="phone">
  </fieldset>
  <button class="btn" id="next">Next Section ▷</button>
  <input type="submit" name="publish" class="btn" id="publish">
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Mary la forma mas simple es poner "required="required" en el html de cada elemento del form.

La otra manera que yo recién implemente es esta:

Se carga un modal mediante un botón, dentro del modal se habilita un input que recibe datos tanto de teclado como desde una pistola para capturar códigos de barra, la siguiente linea habilita el botón que permite realizar una acción con los códigos de barras solo si existe al menos un input que sea crea al vuelo con cada captura de algún código de barras, la linea es esta:

`//Activa el botón Cotejar en caso de encontrar un elemento input
        $('#btnCotejar').attr('disabled', false);`

al botón hay que agregarle el atributo disable:

```
<button type="submit" name="btnCotejar" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnCotejar"  disabled="disable" >Cotejar</button>
```

Y ya con eso se evita el poder realizar el submit u otra acción, si el botón se encuentra deshabilitado.

Comment: ¿Pistola para capturar códigos de barra?

Comment: @EMCode Asi es, quizas la conozcas con otro nombre pero en esencia es esto: https://www.bestbuy.com.mx/p/redlemon-pistola-lector-de-codigos-de-barras-usb-negro/1000219805 esta es de un tipo entre muchas marcas y modelos que existen en el mercado.

Answer (score 0):

Hola hay varios errores de semántica en el formulario, te corregí los que note para que funcionara el script, para "deshabilitar" el botón, se me ocurrió utilizar un elemento extra como auxiliar al que según las condiciones le agregas una clase y te "bloquea" el botón de "next" para que no se de click en el hasta que se cumplan los criterios de los campos no vacíos, ojo, esto solo chequea que el campo no este vació, no que los campos tengan el contenido correcto, eso es una validación extra.

Ahí va el código:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" action="https://formsubmit.co/misrilanka.tk@gmail.com" method="POST">
    <ul id="section-tabs">
      <li class="current active"><span>1.</span> Creds</li>
      <li><span>2.</span> Deets</li>
      <li><span>3.</span> Settings</li>
      <li><span>4.</span> Last Words</li>
    </ul>
  <div id="fieldsets">
  <fieldset class="current">
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input name="email" type="email" class="required email" />
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input name="password" type="password" minlength="10" class="required">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="next">
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input name="username" type="text">
    <label for="bio">Short Bio:</label>
    <textarea name="bio" class="required"></textarea>
    <select name="language">
        <option value="">Idioma</option>
        <option value="es">Español</option>
        <option value="en">Inglés</option>
    </select>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="next">
    <label for="interests">Basic Interests:</label>
    <textarea name="interests"></textarea>
    <p>Receive newsletter?<br>
      <input id="yes" type="radio" name="newsletter" value="yes"><label for="yes">yes</label>
      <input id="no" type="radio" name="newsletter" value="no"><label for="nor">no</label>
    </p>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="next">
    <label for="referrer">Referred by:</label>
    <input type="text" name="referrer">
    <label for="phone">Daytime Phone:</label>
    <input type="tel" name="phone">
  </fieldset>
  <a class="btn" id="next">Next Section ▷</a>
  <span></span>
  <input type="submit" name="publish" class="btn" id="publish">
  </div>
</form>
```

El CSS:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Merriweather Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Merriweather Sans Light'), local('MerriweatherSans-Light'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/merriweathersans/v11/2-c49IRs1JiJN1FRAMjTN5zd9vgsFH1eYCDE0hM.ttf) format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Merriweather Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Merriweather Sans Bold'), local('MerriweatherSans-Bold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/merriweathersans/v11/2-c49IRs1JiJN1FRAMjTN5zd9vgsFH1OZyDE0hM.ttf) format('truetype');
}
body {
  background: url(http://farm5.staticflickr.com/4139/4825532997\_7a7cd3d640\_b.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Merriweather Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #666;
}
#form {
  width: 600px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 80px auto;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 300px;
}
#fieldsets {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}
input[type=text],
input[type=email],
input[type=password],
input[type=tel],
textarea {
  display: block;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  position: relative;
}
input[type=text]:focus,
input[type=email]:focus,
input[type=password]:focus,
input[type=tel]:focus,
textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #22918b;
}
input[type=radio] {
  margin: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
}
fieldset {
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: -640px;
  width: 600px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  opacity: 0;
}
fieldset.current {
  left: 20px;
  opacity: 1;
}
fieldset.next {
  left: 640px;
}
input[type=submit] {
  display: none;
  border: none;
}
#section-tabs {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  list-style: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#section-tabs li {
  color: #a7a7a7;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  border-left: 1px solid #aaa;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 6px;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 30px;
  background: #ddd;
  position: relative;
}
#section-tabs li span {
  color: #bababa;
}
#section-tabs li.active {
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#section-tabs li:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  margin-left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
#section-tabs li.current {
  opacity: 1;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 999;
  border-left: none;
}
#section-tabs li.current:after {
  border: 15px solid transparent;
  border-left: 15px solid #2cbab2;
}
.error {
  color: #bf2424;
  display: block;
}
input.error,
textarea.error {
  border-color: #bf2424;
}
input.error:focus,
textarea.error:focus {
  border-color: #bf2424;
}
label.error {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
input.valid {
  color: green;
}
label.valid {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
}
input + .valid,
textarea + .valid {
  display: none;
}
.valid + .valid {
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  margin-top: -36px;
  color: green;
}
.btn {
  border: none;
  padding: 8px;
  background: #2cbab2;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  font-family: 'Merriweather Sans', sans-serif;
}
.btn:hover {
  background: #26a19a;
}


#next.disabled ~ span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  z-index: 1;  
}
```

El JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(
  function(){
    var btn = $("#next");
    var theForm = $("#form");

    if ($("[name=email]").val() == "" || $("[name=password]").val() == "") {
      btn.addClass("disabled");
    }

    theForm.bind("keyup change",
      function(e){
        var tab = $("#section-tabs li.current span").text();

        switch(tab) {
          case "1.":
            if ($("[name=email]").val() == "" || $("[name=password]").val() == "") {
              btn.addClass("disabled");
            }
            else {
              btn.removeClass("disabled");
            }
          break;

          case "2.":          
           if ($("[name=username]").val() == "" || $("[name=bio]").val() == "" || $("[name=language]").val() == "") {
              btn.addClass("disabled");
            }
            else {
              btn.removeClass("disabled");
            }
          break;

          case "3.":
           if ($("[name=interests]").val() == "" || !$("[name=newsletter]:checked").val()) {
              btn.addClass("disabled");
            }
            else {
              btn.removeClass("disabled");
            }
          break;

          case "4.":
          if ($("[name=referrer]").val() == "" || $("[name=phone]").val() == "") {
              btn.addClass("disabled");
            }
          else {
            btn.removeClass("disabled");
          }
          break;                    
        }
      }
    );

    btn.click(
      function(){
        btn.addClass("disabled");
      }
    );
  }
);

$(document).ready(
  function() {
    $("body").on("keyup", "form", function(e){
    if (e.which == 13){
      if ($("#next").is(":visible") && $("fieldset.current").find("input, textarea").valid() ){
        e.preventDefault();
        nextSection();
        return false;
      }
    }
  });

  $("#next").on("click", function(e){
    console.log(e.target);
    nextSection();
  });

  $("form").on("submit", function(e){
    if ($("#next").is(":visible") || $("fieldset.current").index() < 3){
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });

  function goToSection(i){
    $("fieldset:gt("+i+")").removeClass("current").addClass("next");
    $("fieldset:lt("+i+")").removeClass("current");
    $("li").eq(i).addClass("current").siblings().removeClass("current");
    setTimeout(function(){
      $("fieldset").eq(i).removeClass("next").addClass("current active");
        if ($("fieldset.current").index() == 3){
          $("#next").hide();
          $("input[type=submit]").show();
        } else {
          $("#next").show();
          $("input[type=submit]").hide();
        }
    }, 80);
  }
  function nextSection(){
    var i = $("fieldset.current").index();
    if (i < 3){
      $("li").eq(i+1).addClass("active");
      goToSection(i+1);
    }
  }
  $("li").on("click", function(e){
    var i = $(this).index();
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")){
      goToSection(i);
    } else {
      alert("Please complete previous sections first.");
    }
  });
  }

);
```

Lo puedes tambien probar aca -> https://jsfiddle.net/AugustoM/Lx8o7m5y/

Answer (score -2):

Lo mas conveniente de hacer es simplemente añadir la palabra requiered dentro de la etiquta del input que corresponde a username y language respectivamente. Por ejemplo:
`<input type="text" name="username" required>` y asi igual con cualquier campo que quieras que se obligatorio.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, considera revisar [answer] para que conozcas como realizar respuestas en el sitio, saludos.